# Remove repeated characters

Tags: c++, algorithm, strings

I was trying this problem from a competitive forum:

> Remove the repeated characters from the input string and output the
>   resulted string.
>
> - Input string: "abcabd"
> - Output string: "abcd"

The minimum test cases are passed. Please provide your comments.

```
string input = "abcabd";
string output;

int len = input.length();

for(int i=0; i<len;i++)
{
    bool flag = false;
    int len2 = output.length();
    for(int j=0;j< len2;j++)
    {
        if(input[i]==output[j])
        {
            flag = true;
            break;
        }           
    }
    if(!flag)
    {
        output = output + input[i];
    }
}

cout << output.c_str() << endl;
```

Comment: This code can't possibly compile as shown. There is no function wrapping the code. There is no using namespace std; or using std::cout;

Comment: I didnt add it. I have the other functions and statments. hence didnt put it.

Comment: @funwithlinx Please include the full code.

Comment: Please present commented code ready to run (and accomplish its goal), only.

Answer (score 4):

### Overview:

I don't like the fact you have not provided functional code. Next time please provide a compilable function.

### Technique

Sure that solution looks like it will work. But the second loop is unnecessary. Your solution is `O(n)` (n size of alphabet) and will break down if the string encoding is unicode.

It is quite easy to build a solution that is `O(1)`. For ASCII characters a simple array of 255 elements can be used. If you want to handle unicode then you way want an `unordered_set` to achieve the same result.

```
char used[256] = {0}; // zero fills the array.

for(int i=0; i<len;i++)
{
    if (!used[input[i]]) {
        // STUFF
    }
}
```

### Prefer Iterators to indexing

You should get used to using iterators. Whenever scanning something iterators are the preferred method. This is because they are generalized and all the algorithms use them. This make writting genric functions for any container much easier.

```
// Choice 1:
for(auto const& v: input)      // Range based for (uses iterators behind the scene)
{
}

// Choice 2:  use begin/end functions (as they even work on arrays)
for(auto loop = std::begin(input); loop != std::end(input); ++loop)
{
}

// Choice 3: use begin/end methods
for(auto loop = input.begin(); loop != input.end(); ++loop)
{
}

// Choice 4: use indexing.
for(std::size_t loop = 0; loop < input.length(); ++loop)
{
}
```

But if you can prefer a standard algorithm over a manual loop (see below)

### Use existing algorithms to make your code simpler.

Depending on how you interpret the question. There are a couple of ways to do this; but they all are going to incorporate a functor of some description that filters characters. So if we write that first.

```
bool used[256] = {0};
auto test      = [&used](unsigned char x){bool r = used[x];used[x] = 1;return r;};
```

The output of a function could be a return value. In this case I would have used the `Erase Remove Idiom`.

```
auto newEnd = std::erase(std::begin(input), std::end(input), test);
std::remove(newEnd, std::end(input));
return input;
```

Alternatively (as you interpreted) it could be output to `std::cout`. In this case I would simply use copy_if algorithm

```
std::copy_if(std::begin(input), std::end(input),
             std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout),
             test);
```

#### Code Review

```
int len = input.length();

for(int i=0; i<len;i++)
```

Sure that seems like a good optimization. In reality that is unlikely to be any faster (as the compiler will do that optimization automatically). So I would just do this (for clarity).

```
for(std::size_t i=0; i< input.length(); i++)
```

### Prefer `"\n"` over `std::endl`

```
cout << output.c_str() << endl;
```

The difference between the two is that `std::endl` forces the stream to flush. Flushing the stream manually usually causes worse performance (there is no real reason to do it as the stream will flush itself).

### Never Do this.

```
using namespace std;
```

I can see from the this code:

```
cout << output.c_str() << endl;
```

That you have done this in some code that you did not share with us.

If you had read any other C++ review on this board it would have told you not to do this. See: [Why is “using namespace std” in C++ considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice/1453605#1453605).

There is a reason that the standard libraries are called std and not standard. Its to make prefixing them easy.

Comment: Not sure about the `for` loop comment.  The two are semantically different.  Having a length check in the conditional semantically means "could mutate, check every iteration".  Saving the length as a constant and comparing against that signals that the loop is just scanning.  For clarity, use a range-based `for` or an existing algorithm.  In the rare case you have to write a raw index-based `for` loop, write the version that best semantically expresses intent.

Comment: @Snowhawk04 True. But because on const correctness (an important factor in C++) it is simple for the compiler to determine if a container could be mutated and thus perform the optimization of yanking the end test calculation out of the loop. What the OP has done is basically a premature optimization and what I present is the general case.

Answer (score 2):

I think @Loki has given a good review in general, but I think he's missed out on one point that's worth making.

#### Choose appropriate data structures

Although he doesn't point it out explicitly, he does actually point to an alternative data structure--creating a set as an array of `bool`. Compared to the original (which scans through the current output characters to see if it already contains the current character) this can improve efficiency considerably. In particular, it changes this from an \$O(N^2)\$ algorithm to an \$O(N)\$ algorithm.

For this case, that general idea is probably fairly reasonable. In particular, when you're dealing with `char` there are typically only about 256 values, and an array of 256 bools is quite manageable.

If, on the other hand, you were going to deal with Unicode input (e.g., `std::wstring`) that choice becomes a quite a bit less reasonable in a hurry. Unicode supports about a million code points. Many implementations use 4 bytes for a `bool`, so that would use up about 4 megabytes of memory (most of which wouldn't be used in any particular invocation, unless you routinely dealt with files that contained a mixture of essentially every language on earth.

In this case, it would probably be worthwhile to use something like an `std::unordered_set` to give roughly the same effect (see if we've already seen a character in constant time) without allocating memory for every *possible* value, most of which we expect to sit idle in nearly every use.

As it happens, `std::unordered_set` returns a value that will tell us if an insertion was successful (i.e., the character hadn't been seen yet), so we can use that to determine whether we've already output that character.

```
std::unordered_set<char> seen;

std::copy_if(input.begin(), input.end(), 
    std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout),
    [](char ch) { return seen.insert(ch).second; });
```

Another possibility (quite possibly the best one, in this case) would be to use a `std::vector<bool>` instead. This is a somewhat controversial choice--a fair number of people would (and do) advise against using `std::vector<bool>` ever, under any circumstances. To an extent I can see their point (`std::vector<bool>` doesn't follow the rules for a container, even though `std::vector<T>` for every type other than `bool` does). In this particular case, however, the choices made in `std::vector<bool>` are likely to work out fairly well for `char` and considerably better for `wchar_t` or something similar (something that can represent Unicode code points).

The reason is that `std::vector<bool>` stores each Boolean value in a single bit. That takes a little extra work on the part of the CPU, but reduces memory usage by a fairly large margin (at least 8:1, quite often 32:1).

There's one more point that applies with either `vector<bool>` or an array of `bool` (or would with `std:queue<bool>`, etc.). That's the simple fact that `char` can be either signed or unsigned. Since it can be signed, we don't want to use a `char` value directly as an index into a collection that uses indices from 0 to N. If we do, a negative character value will give undefined behavior when we try to index a nonexistent location.

What we typically want to do is cast the value to the corresponding unsigned type, so for `char` we want `unsigned char`.

```
std::vector<bool> seen;

// ...
seen[(unsigned char)ch] = true;
```

Here again, LokiAstari has done the job exactly correctly (converted the value to an unsigned char before using it as an index) but hasn't really pointed out in the text why he did it, or how it's important (though I think it would be better to get the maximum value for an unsigned char rather than hard-coding it: `bool used[std:numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max()] = {0};`).